# After executing a shell script, the QT GUI is blocked

Tags: qt, shell

I have a GUI implemented with QT. The GUI has many buttons and one of them executes a shell script:

```
system("/bin/sh executeScene.sh");
```

The script is executed properly but, the GUI is blocked until I close the script that was previously called. Is there a way to execute my shell script without blocking the GUI?

The GUI has another button to stop the shell script but, as the GUI is blocked, I cannot stop the script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`QProcess`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprocess.html) to run the process asynchronously.

Answer (score 2):

hye, i used this for one of my GUI applications...

```
    void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
    {
        QProcess process;
        process.startDetached("/bin/sh", QStringList()<< "/path/to/your/shell.sh");
    }
```